# Message box confirmation on button press

Tags: vb.net, forms, button

I have a problem where my code clears regardless if I press yes or no inside my message box. I believe i could probably get rid of my if statments as well i dont know why i included them like that

```vb
Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    If MsgBox("Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question = DialogResult.Yes) Then

        If (chkLevel3Support.Checked) Then
            chkLevel3Support.Checked = False
        End If

        If (chkOnSiteTraining.Checked) Then
            chkOnSiteTraining.Checked = False
        End If

        If (chkCloudBackup.Checked) Then
            chkCloudBackup.Checked = False
        End If

        If (rdbYearlyLicense.Checked) Then
            rdbYearlyLicense.Checked = False
        End If

        If (rdbOneTIme.Checked) Then
            rdbOneTIme.Checked = False
        End If

        lbCostofLicenseOutput.Text = " "

        lbCostofOptionalOutput.Text = " "

        lbTotalCostSale.Text = " "
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you presented has no MessageBox. Did you mean to include the commented code? Can you please fix it so it represents your actual code?

Comment: Please use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) to let Visual Studio tell you where the problems are.

Comment: There is no point in checking for `chkLevel3Support.Checked`, and so on, if it has to end up as `False` anyway.

Comment: You probably meant `If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm clear", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton don't forget about CheckState.Intermediate :) `chkLevel3Support.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate` `If chkLevel3Support.Checked Then chkLevel3Support.Checked = False`

Comment: @djv Lol, I guess no-one was sure if that would be in the spec :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your right parenthesis in in the wrong spot.  Try this:

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
```

or doing it the .NET way as proposed by Andrew:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm clear", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
```

Comment: Close, but that second parameter should be a `MsgBoxStyle`. The dangers of not using Option Strict On are many.

Comment: That fixed it! i can believe i spent so long and did not notice! i appreciate it

Comment: @AndrewMorton That's also the danger of relying on memory and not reading carefully.